Python IMAP get all the messages from one conversation via latest message id
I am using Python and imapib. I have a message id of a specific message. If that message is part of conversation (I think it's called thread, I am really unfamiliar with the standard) I need to get list of all previous messages in that conversation, preferably sorted by time. I can get raw email, thread topic and index, but so far everything that I've tried to get all the previous messages failed, due to my lacking knowledge of the standard. I am avoiding diving deep into it, since I'm quite overwhelmed with work, but maybe I'll have to. Please, help. Any library is allowed.

What you want is basically to split the References: header and fetch those messages by their Message-Id:; sorting or otherwise arranging them is then up to you, though you can basically count on the References: header to be sorted chronologically. (Though for really long threads, the older messages will be dropped; you may have to work your way back by parsing the References: of incrasingly older messages.)
Also keep in mind that each message is the head of a branch; the starting message may have many additional threads attached to it which would have branched off the trunk (however you like to define that) at various points. To get every child message which links back to it, you basically have to examine all subsequent messages and determine from their References: whether they link back to a message you are interested in.
https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html has a succinct overview of the headers involved and their semantics; you should probably also
have at least basic familiarity with RFC5322. The sibling pages at https://cr.yp.to/immhf/ are also well worth your attention.
Here is a brief demo of how to fetch one message and the ones in its References: header, using imaplib from the Python standard library.
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
from email import message_from_bytes
from email.policy import default


SERVER = 'imap.example.com'
EMAIL = 'you@example.com'
PASSWORD = 'pa$$w*rd'
MESGID = '<friendlyreminder1234567890@example.net>'

with IMAP4_SSL(SERVER, 993) as imap:
    imap.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    imap.select('INBOX')
    status, base_search = imap.search(None, 'header', f'Message-Id "{MESGID}"')
    assert status == 'OK'
    base_uid = base_search[0].split()
    assert len(base_uid) == 1
    status, data = imap.fetch(base_uid[0], '(RFC822)')
    assert status == 'OK'
    base_message = message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=default)
    print(base_message.as_string())
    references = base_message.get('References')
    if references is not None:
        for message_id in references.split():
            status, uid_search = imap.search(None, 'header', f'Message-Id "{message_id}"')
            assert status == 'OK'
            if uid_search == [b'']:
                print("could not fetch", message_id)
                continue
            assert len(uid_search) == 1
            _, data = imap.fetch(uid_search[0], '(RFC822)')
            message = message_from_bytes(data[1], policy=default)
            print("-" * 72)
            print(message.as_string())

imaplib is messy and IMAP is messy. You might want to look for a third-party library which shields you from some of the messiness.
This takes care to use the modern email library with email.policy; you will find many examples which show the pre-3.6 email library (or worse, often using message_from_string instead of the proper message_from_bytes).

If you are lucky, your server will support THREAD=REFERENCES and do the hard work for you, but it is optional and you can’t count on it existing.

This seems to do something, but some messages are grouped together in HTML... So I am not getting messages one by one as intended. Since imap is messy, are there some alternative libs/wrappers for python that could abstract this process somehow on high level?

I don't understand "grouped together in HTML". E.g. IMAPClient purports to be a friendlier alternative but I don't have any experience with it.
